# How to restore the following elliptical constructions into a complete sentence?

Tags: usage, word-order

Here is a dictionary example : *Er arbeitet langsam, dafür aber gründlich.*
I think the second part *dafür aber gründlich* is an ellipsis of a complete clause and I'd like to know what the complete clause should be like;
i.e. which one of the following would be the proper completion of the ellipsis, in that the *aber* in the sentence have the same focus as that *aber* in the elliptical form aforestated?
1. *Er arbeitet langsam; dafür ist er aber gründlich* , or
2. *Er arbeitet langsam; dafür aber ist er gründlich* , or
3. *Er arbeitet langsam; er ist dafür aber gründlich*

If none of these furnishes a proper completion of the given ellipsis, could any one tell what the proper completion should be?

Answer (score 5):

> Als Ellipse (griechisch ἔλλειψις élleipsis „Fehlen“, „Aussparung“, „Auslassung“) bezeichnet man das Auslassen von Satzteilen, aber auch die Sätze mit diesen Auslassungen. Häufig wird das Prädikat ausgelassen.

*Quelle: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_%28Linguistik%29*

Which does indeed apply to your question. I would not consider the second part a *complete clause* (as in *Hauptsatz*), but rather a Nebensatz, specifically an [Adversativsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adversativsatz), opposing the *langsam* and the *gründlich*. So the full sentence would be

> Er arbeitet langsam, **dafür aber arbeitet er gründlich.**

Since the *arbeitet er* is completely redundant with the first part, it is left out in your example.

Comment: 'dafür aber arbeitet (...)' klingt für mich ein bissel unrund. 'er arbeitet langsam, dafür arbeitet er aber gründlich' fände ich an der Stelle besser

Comment: Beide Formulierungen finde ich recht umständlich. Das wird der Grund sein, warum 'arbeitet er' im Original nicht auftaucht.

Comment: »Dafür aber arbeitet er gründlich« ist ein Hauptsatz. Das Verb ist zu weit vorne für einen Nebensatz.